# How to get the Roles and Attributes of a Keycloak User

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

How do I get the roles and attributes of a user using the Java Client of Keycloak? Below is the code that I have written to get the access token of a user, however, I am not able to find the way to get the roles assigned to that user.

```java
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setRealm("foo");
configuration.setResource("foo");
configuration.setBearerOnly(Boolean.TRUE);
configuration.setAuthServerUrl("http://localhost:8080");
configuration.setCredentials(Map.of("secret", "FV3P4ajYHedAUDtOa55EX5nzK8zc6jUA"));


AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create(configuration);
AuthorizationRequest request = new AuthorizationRequest();


AuthorizationResponse authorize = authzClient.authorization("john.doe", "john.doe").authorize(request);
String token = authorize.getToken();
log.info("Auth bearer token is {}", token);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the token as a `String`, namely:

```
String token = authorize.getToken();
```

now you just need to parse it to get the Realm and Client roles, which are encoded in the token. For that you can use the [class TokenVerifier](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/TokenVerifier.html) from `org.keycloak.TokenVerifier`.

For example:

```
try {
    AccessToken token = TokenVerifier.create(tokenString, AccessToken.class).getToken();
    System.out.printf("Realm 'foo' = Roles %s%n", token.getRealmAccess().getRoles());

    token.getResourceAccess().forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("Client '%s' = Roles '%s'%n", k, v.getRoles()));
} catch (VerificationException e) {
    ...
}
```